# Analytics - Session Path - Problems

Tags: dialogflow-es

We are implementing a bot in Dialgflow Essential and have encountered some problems when viewing statistics.

Is there a way to see analytics in real time? When doing tests we see that today's interactions do not appear, only those from days past.

In Analytics - Session Path we have encountered the following problem: If one day there are no interactions with the bot, the session path shows the session count of the last search that was done. For example, if we look for interactions from two days ago, and there are 4 sessions, if there are none today, instead of 0 appearing, 4 appear; But if we search for the interactions from two weeks ago and there are 15, when we search again for today's interactions, we find 15.

This is confusing to keep track of.

Can anyone help us?

Thank you.